# AWS: Best solution for syncing files across autoscaled EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, s3fs

I'm working on setting up autoscaling on EC2; Instances will be running a web app with big traffic spikes. The first solution I tried for syncing files across instances (since the web app will write files to disk) was S3 with s3fs for mounting. However, even light load testing resulted in s3fs hogging the CPU (which is strange since s3fs is configured to use local cache).

Is there another way to utilize S3 for this purpose (possibly reconfigure s3fs), or do I need to look into other solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

on ec2, i would sync across instances via pki and rsync, as that would be *way* faster than s3.  another option, if there is a huge amount of data, is to rsync to an ebs mount, and then unmount, detach, re-attach on next instance, mount, rsync, unmount, detach, next instance,.... etc

passing an ebs volume around for local rsyncing is pretty easy to script with aws ec2 cli api tools.